# issue while calling post using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was making jQuery post method call and while coding I missed the `.` between `$` and post...i.e. I wrote it like

```
$post(url, data function(o){
   //do something with o;
});
```

The post worked but the page was getting refreshed and I spend a lot of time figuring what was wrong.

I want to know what is the difference b/w `$post` and `$.post` (that is if `$post` is a valid JQuery command)?

Comment: `$.post` is the real way, `$post` is likely a jQuery internal method.

Comment: $.post() method loads data from the server. it uses a HTTP POST request and $post it is a variable!

Comment: If you were calling the post after the user submit a form, most likely a JS error stop your script and the form was submitted normally (e.g. page refresh).

Comment: Nogray... your explanation sounds most reasonable as I had a return false statement at the end of the JQuery block. Also I slapped in some alerts before and within the post statement. The one before was getting executed and after the post statement in JQuery is encountered the page simply reloads.

Answer (score 5):

`$post` will be just a variable and nothing more.

If you didn't define a function with name `$post` or assign a function to `$post`, you will get

```
ReferenceError: $post is not defined
```

error in your console.

> I spend a lot of time figuring what was wrong.

**Check the console see if there are any error first, it will save you a lot of time.**